# model.show is not working correctly not getting the id into the controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel

so my route is this

```
Route::resource('/rentals', 'RentalsController',);
```

and my model is this

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class rentals extends Model
{
    public function avaliablities() {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\avaliablities');
    }
    public function reviews() {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\reviews');
    }
    public function reservations() {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\reservations');
    }
}
```

and the part of the controller in function is this

```
    public function show(rentals $rentals)
    {
        dd($rentals);
        $rental = \App\Rentals::with('reviews')->find($rental->id);

        dd($rental);
        return view('detail', compact('rentals'));
    }
```

but when i do the dump and die $rentals there is nothing in it but it also gives no error. (edit it does say it is an int and is an id)

so i am stuck at this and have no idee to fix it probaly something with my routes but i tried the get but that just broke everything when i did

```
Route::get('/rentals/{id}','RentalsController@show', );
```

and i am totaly out of idee's

and in previous projects where i used laravel this did work. and as shown here i get the data of the id again from the database so you can go to the page via a link and it doesn't break and also gets updated

and checked if i didn't make a custom id by accedent in the seeder but it looked fine

Comment: feel free to ask for anything of edit my grammer or stuff like that

Comment: Change the route to parameter to the model name instead of id

Comment: @user1105056 do you mean this     `Route::resource('/rentals/{id}', 'RentalsController@show',);
`
becouse i don't realy understand your commet

Comment: I'm seeing some inconsistencies with the casing of your model name! is it rentals or Rentals. plus are you importing the namespace in your controller or not because you're typehinting rentals instead or \App\Rentals?

Comment: You need to read this.. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#implicit-binding

Comment: @Rabah you mean about my import that works fine and should be like this and is also how it is in the standard controller of a new laravel project

Comment: And better read this... https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#explicit-binding

Comment: i added an answer that explains why but wil give probs to the right answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
Route::get('/Rentals/{rentals}','RentalsController@show', );
```

Comment: this does work but i would rather want to use resources it is so weird that the resource doesn't work here and worked for me fine in the past

Comment: check my comment

Answer (score 0):

the problem i had i wil give noman the probs for the right answer this is correct

```
Route::get('/Rentals/{rentals}','RentalsController@show', );
```

but what happands with the resource for some reason it got rid of the s while making the routes

look at the picture i added
[image: so as shown here]

and i don't think there is anyway to fix this in the code without maby a lot of work

so if you use the cmd to make all the links and want to use the resources don't make it plural (so multiple) but make it one rental

and that should fix the resources